# Can we publish SNAPSHOT versioned artifacts to release repo?

Tags: maven-3, versioning, artifactory

Can we publish 1.0-SNAPSHOT versioned artifacts to release repo? else should be manually update the pom.xml's version to 1.0 or 1.1 or 1.2 .. (release version) every time we build on release and master branches?
Doing so we may not be able to download SNAPSHOT artifacts from release repo, please suggest if there are any best practises to it.

Comment: There are several ways of handling versioning, but you should not put your snapshot artefacts in the release repo. Personally I prefer the simple maven versions plugin. Maven release plugin is also very popular. I would recommend to have this part handled in a pipeline in a CI tool such as Jenkins. Makes it easy to maintain.

Comment: Thanks Vegard, i find this helpful http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/update-versions.html  
mvn release:update-versions

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, Balasa!

There are a couple of ways to promote a snapshot to a release. One of them would be the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/), another – renaming the snapshot artifacts to releases on the fly using [an Artifactory user plugin](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/build/promotion).